# What are the graph classes which takes logarithmic space in $|V|$ in circuit representation?

Tags: data-structures, succinct-data-structures

The $\text{SCR}$ representation of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is $C_{G}$ id the following conditions hold:

- $C_{G}$ is a combinatorial circuit with memory.
- $C_{G}$ has two inputs of length $n$ bits.
- $C_{G}$ has $r$ gates, where $r = \mathcal{O}(n^{k})$ for some integer $k$. [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995883800047)
- The output of $C_{G}$ is 
  $$C_{G}(i',j') = 0, \text{if } (v_i,v_j) \in E$$
  $$C_{G}(i',j') = 1, \text{if } (v_i,v_j) \notin E$$
  $$C_{G}(i',j') = ?, \text{if } (v_i \in V) \text{ or } (v_j \notin V) $$

The binary representation of $i$ is $i'$. For certain graphs there is a representation in $\text{SCR}$ that takes logarithmic space in $|V|$.

**Question :**  What are the graph classes(bounded degree, planar etc) which takes logarithmic space representation in $\text{SCR}$ model?

[image]

Comment: What is the *space* of a representation? When is it logarithmic?

Comment: Where is your quote taken from?

Comment: None of your graph classes have succinct representations in general. This should follow from a counting argument. Having a succinct representation is a special property. Some expander graphs can be described succinctly, as are simple graphs such as cycles and paths.

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus It is taken from the link mentioned in the comment.